# How to change the order for two items in .each in ruby

Tags: ruby, select, each

I have a function in my .erb file and in it I have the following:

```
<%select id ="dropdown">
<option disabled selected value="select"> - select - </option> 
<% @variable.each do |x| %> 
<%= "<option value='#{x['code']}'>#{x['description']}         </option>".html_safe %>
<% end %>
<%/select>
```

But I need to have two items (TUA and CRL) to be displayed at the top and the rest to be displayed in alpha order (which currently is)  so it should be .

```
<%select id ="dropdown">
<option disabled selected value="select"> - select - </option> 
<% @variable.each do |x| %>
<% next if x['code'] == 'TUA' or x['code'] == 'CRL' %> 
<%= "<option value='#{x['code']}'>#{x['description']}         </option>".html_safe %>
<% end %>
<%/select>
```

How can I do that ? I have hardcoded it and I don't want that.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how @variable is declared, but what if you try arranging it in the controller?

```
@variable = []
@variable << Variable.find_by(code: 'TUA')
@variable << Variable.find_by(code: 'CRL')

@variables = Variable.all.order('code DESC')
@variables.each do |x|
  if x.code != 'TUA' && x.code!= 'CRL'
    @variable << x
  end
end
```

Comment: @variable is defined in the controller and it's a Web service return call.

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work. Also I need to have the fix in the erb file and not in the controller.  I'm still trying to figure it out.

Comment: Why didn't it work - the more description you give, the easier it will be to help you solve. Why do you need it in the .erb file? It is best practice to declare your variables in the controller, and load them with the page.